# Reusable real time display with jQuery

Tags: jquery, data-binding, real-time

I'm attempting to update some text fields based on the the data that is entered into an input field in real time using jQuery. I have gotten a rough example of this working, but it's not very reusable at it requires a function be created for each input. I was hoping that there might be a more dynamic/efficient way to perform the same task?

```js
$('#name').keyup(function () {
        $('#label-name').text($(this).val());
    });

    $('#address').keyup(function () {
        $('#label-address').text($(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Address">
    <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City">
    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="none">--</option>
        <option value="state1">State 1</option>
        <option value="state2">State 2</option>
    </select>
    <input id="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip">
    <input id="additional" type="text" placeholder="Additional info">
    
    <p id="label-name"></p>
    <p id="label-address"></p>
    <p id="label-city"></p>
    <p id="label-state"></p>
    <p id="label-zip"></p>
    <p id="label-additional"></p>
```

Comment: How would you target elements without specific selectors ?

Comment: "real time updating". Well you'll either need `sockets`, `long-polling` or `node.js` depending on what your sever setup is if you want to use `node.js`

Comment: You wouldn't, that was poorly phrased on my part. The way that I've succeeded in making this happens requires a new function be created for each individual input. That seems inefficient.

Comment: Oh, I see. Give the inputs a class and do `$('.input').on('keyup', function() { $('#label-' + this.id).text(this.value); });`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aJuH5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the `id`s will always be related as you've shown, you could add a class to your inputs and do something like this:

```
$('.input').keyup(function () {
    $('#label-' + this.id).text(this.value);
});
```